# C#: How to access GridView (a non-static field) in a static method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, webforms

I need to retrieve all rows from GridView1 and export to excel using C#.
This static method below is called by Ajax however it says the GridView1 is a non-static field so I could not proceed. Is it possible to change the GridView1 to static field? Thanks in advance

```
 [WebMethod]
     public static string ExportExcel()
     {
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        return null;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

## 1 can you create non static method then best.

OR

## 2 Create a class and method and call that method

```
  [WebMethod]
     public static string ExportExcel()
     {
        Export objExort = new Export();
        return    objExort.Excel();
       
     }

     public class Export
        {
            public string Excel()
            {
                 GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Second option still will show error: 
Error CS0038 Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'namespace' via nested type 'namespace.newclass' Web D:\~\pagename.aspx.cs